# What is the advantage to using a representation vs a layer file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, representation

I understand that the representation stores the symbology inside of the geodatabase.  It creates it's own field for a RuleID.  I made a layer file that had 'unique values and many fields' and chose two fields illustrated in my screenshot.

[image]
This makes the analyst pick two fields in order to be attributed correctly.  When I make representation based off of this layer this is what appears in the Layer Properties.

[image]

I get what is going on between them.  With a representation it moves the symbology into a new field (rule ID) that is attributed when you create a new feature.  The problem I have is I want the original fields that made up the RuleID attributed.  The picture below shows the RuleID field based on what I created.  It's based off the Type of Facility and Status (not pictured).
[image]

Is there a way to attribute the original fields, but still have the symbology built in the GDB?  Am I better off using layer files and resourcing to the current GDB for every client? I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and about to upgrade to 10.2.2 in a few weeks.

Comment: You can change the representation without affecting the geometry. It's more for Cartographic Styling and Output http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000004m000000

Comment: Your layer files *should* be forward compatible, databases too. ArcGis hasn't had problems going forward that I'm aware of; the only version compatibility probem you might encounter is if create/update in 10.2.2 and try to open in 10.1. In representations you can alter the shame and suppress drawing of individual features - this may lead to problems as you're no longer accurately reflecting the features.

Comment: If you can create a cartographic effect you want with layer's symbology alone then stick with layers.  Representations are, IMHO, a bit of a train wreck. Too much complexity for not enough functionality. Like many late ESRI features it sounds good on paper but, at least for my workflow, it didn't really work in reality.